# Return line above pattern in file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have output like so

```
v12:     "owner" : "cs1372",
v12:     "num-of-connections" : 1,
v12:     "owner" : "cq5838",
v5:     "owner" : "bb9886",
v5:     "owner" : "aq0903",
v5:     "owner" : "bj2468",
v5:     "owner" : "di3080",
v5:     "num-of-connections" : 1,
```

I need to return the line above the num-of-connections line. So what I want in this output is

```
v12:     "owner" : "cs1372",
v5:     "owner" : "di3080",
```

Is there an easy way to do this with sed or awk?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '$2=="\"num-of-connections\""{ print prev } { prev=$0 }' file
v12:     "owner" : "cs1372",
v5:     "owner" : "di3080",
```

Save the current record in variable `prev`. If the second field equals `"num-of-connections"`, print variable `prev`.